# Запрос POST посылает пустой req.body

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, json, ajax

Отправляю значения в формате JSON с помощью jQuery запросом AJAX. Запрос GET работает корректно, в то же время когда POST посылает пустой req (req.body = undefined). В чем может быть проблема?

Отправка запроса:

```
$.post("http://localhost:8080/api/set", {
    "myData": numbers,
    "asc": "true"
}, function(data, status){
    alert("Данные: " + JSON.stringify(data) + "\nСостояние: " + status);
});
$.get("http://localhost:8080/api/get", function(data, status){
    alert("Data: " + JSON.stringify(data) + "\nStatus: " + status);
});
```

Создание сервера:

```
require('dotenv').config()
const express = require('express')
const { error } = require('console')
const PORT= process.env.PORT || 8080
const cors = require('cors')
const router = require('./routes/index')
const app = express()

app.use(cors())
app.options('*', cors());
app.use(express.json())
app.use('/api', router)


const start = async () => {
    try {
        app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`))
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}
start()
```

Получение запросов:

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router();
const fs= require('fs')
const _ = require('lodash');
const $ = require('jquery');

router.post('/set', (req, res)=>{
   const {myData, asc} = req.body
   console.log(myData);
   let clone = myData.slice(0)
    let sortedArr = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        let arr = [];
        let index = i;
        for(let j = 0; j < 10; j++){
            arr[j] = clone[index];
            index += 8;
        }
        arr.sort(function(a, b) {
            return asc === 'true' ? a - b : b - a;
        });
        sortedArr[i] = arr;
    }
    let arr = [];
    let index = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            arr[index++] = sortedArr[j][i];
        }
    }
   fs.mkdir('./files', ()=>{
      fs.writeFile('./files/didntSorted.txt', myData.join(', '), (error)=>{
          error? console.log(error): null;
      })
      fs.writeFile('./files/sorted.txt', arr.join(', '), (error)=>{
         error? console.log(error): null;
     })
  })
   let obj={
      myData: myData,
      clone: arr
   }
   return  res.json(obj)
})

router.get('/get', (req, res)=>{
    console.log('get');
   let obj = {}
   fs.mkdir('./files', ()=>{
      if(fs.existsSync('./files/didntSorted.txt')){
         obj.didntSorted = fs.readFileSync('./files/didntSorted.txt','utf8')
      }
      else  obj.didntSorted = ''
      if(fs.existsSync('./files/sorted.txt')){
         obj.sorted = fs.readFileSync('./files/sorted.txt','utf8')
      }
      else  obj.sorted = ''
     
      return  res.json(obj)
  })
})

module.exports = router
```

Comment: еще раз добрый день, проблему решил, спасибо

Comment: Так добавьте ответ либо удалите вопрос.

Comment: ответил, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помогла отправка "Content-Type", а именно:

```
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
```

Comment: да, это очень важно в post-запросах, уж не знаю почему